# How do I apply SSAO (screen space ambient occlusion) to MSAA? (multi-sample anti-aliasing)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I can get SSAO to work without any anti-aliasing on a framebuffer. However when I successfully apply MSAA x4 anti-aliasing to my textures, then blit them to an intermediate framebuffer, SSAO doesn't work properly and I get these 4 quadrants with dark artefacts.

Without MSAA applied
[image: SSAO working without any MSAA applied]

When MSAA x4 is applied to intermediate framebuffer object, now the SSAO has these 4 dark quadrant artefacts.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I think I answered my own question. Apparently it does NOT anti-alias any effects coming out of the shader. In other words, it works perfectly fine for forward rendering but does NOT work in deferred rendering because lighting decisions are made after the MSAA has resolved.

Also on Wiki it states that fragment shader effects are immune to MSAA unfortunately. So I must consider FXAA instead. Thank you and good night!